# What does " = 0" here mean?

Tags: c++

```
int foo (int a , int b = 0)
```

I just read this code. I don't understand what " = 0" means?

I would also like to know why `int foo (int a = 0, int b)` does not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See

[Default Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

b is a parameter with a default value of 0.  So the function can be called (e.g.):

```
foo(3, 4)
```

with a and b equal to 3 and 4

or:

```
foo(5)
```

with a and b equal to 5 and 0.

```
int foo (int a=0, int b)
```

is wrong because default parameters can only appear at the end.  Imagine you had:

```
int foo (int a = 0, int b, int c = 1)
```

and called it like:

```
foo(3, 4)
```

The compiler wouldn't know which you were omitting.  To avoid such situations, you can't put a default parameter before a non-default one.

Answer (score 2):

It sets the default value for the parameter "b" to the function foo, so that the call `foo(345)` is equivalent to the call `foo(345, 0)`